# Is there any way to download Packages (Nuget) from TeamCity?

Tags: nuget, teamcity

I need to extract dependencies from team city build. Does anyone know how to download packages from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just sent a request to `https://your.teamcity.url.com/repository/download/YourBuildConfigurationId/123:id/path/to/artifact.nupkg` where `123` is the build ID you are interested in.

See [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/rest/teamcity-rest-api-documentation.html#REST+Authentication) on details about authentication